# Creating Regex expression for hard coded digits in a string

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex expressions. Basically i am trying to search if the number is valid or not.

Number Format is `923 x g yyyyyyy`

I want regex which detects starting three to be `923` , then x should be less than 7 and g and y can be any numbers from `0-9.` i HAVE tried understanding regex but i can't find anything .

Anyone can make regex and then explain a little how it actually works

Comment: *i HAVE tried understanding regex but i can't find anything .* I recommend 2 sites: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/). Do you have some code, BTW? Please post your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^923 [0-6] [0-9] [0-9]{7}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN4rN3/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^         # Start
923       # 923 at start
" "       # match a space (without quotes)
[0-6]     # [0-9] (match a digit less than 7)
" "       # match a space (without quotes)
[0-9]     # [0-9] (any digit)
" "       # match a space (without quotes)
[0-9]{7}  # 7 repeats of [0-9] (any digit)
$         # Line end
```

Comment: If u can explain that would be great

Answer (score 0):

This regex will search for combination of POO(fixed string starts with ^) + DIGIT(5 digit must)
For Digit

```
\A^POO\d{5}\z
```

This regex will search for combination of POO(fixed string starts with ^) + DIGIT(1 to 5 digit range) {1,5} is range identifier

```
\A^POO\d{1,5}\z
```

This regex will search for combination of POO(fixed string starts with ^) + Alphanumeric(5 max any combination or char and digit like A1234,ABDFG, 12345, AAA12 etc...)
For Alphanumeric

```
\A^POO\w{5}\z
```